# How do I list all of my Jenkins credentials in the script console?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, mercurial

I'm trying to get Jenkins to clone my mercurial project from BitBucket. It won't, because it *says* there's a problem with the credentials - well, bitbucket is refusing whatever it is that Jenkins is providing.

I'm almost 100% sure that Jenkins is not providing what it should be providing, because when I run

```
hg clone --ssh="ssh -i /path/to/my/key" ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/my-org/my-repo
```

It clones a-OK. The contents of `/path/to/my/key` are what I put in the key in Jenkins' credentials manager. I've verified that it is found in my jenkins `credentials.xml` file.

And *yet*, when I try to run my job? Clone fails because

```
remote: Host key verification failed.
```

That leads me to believe that the problem is with whatever is getting passed via the mercurial plugin. But I can't see it in the log because it's some sort of [masked string](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mercurial-plugin/blob/17a01f2097e3a90568b42705c9a0d223695bdef5/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/mercurial/HgExe.java#L155) and just displays as `******`.

So I wanted to make sure that the credentials that are going to the Hg plugin are, in fact, what's present in my `credentials.xml` file.

So far I've made it to here:

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials


def creds = CredentialsProvider.all()
print creds
```

Which gives me a list of credentials providers... but I'm not sure where to go next. I've been drowning in documentation trying to figure out how to get at the credential information that I want... but no dice.

(How) can I take what I've got and display a list of my Jenkins credentials in the Groovy script console?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This works very well for me...

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
      com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class
)

for (c in creds) {
  println(c.id)
  if (c.properties.description) {
    println("   description: " + c.description)
  }
  if (c.properties.username) {
    println("   username: " + c.username)
  }
  if (c.properties.password) {
    println("   password: " + c.password)
  }
  if (c.properties.passphrase) {
    println("   passphrase: " + c.passphrase)
  }
  if (c.properties.secret) {
    println("   secret: " + c.secret)
  }
  if (c.properties.secretBytes) {
    println("    secretBytes: ")
    println("\n" + new String(c.secretBytes.getPlainData(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    println("")
  }
  if (c.properties.privateKeySource) {
    println("   privateKey: " + c.getPrivateKey())
  }
  if (c.properties.apiToken) {
    println("   apiToken: " + c.apiToken)
  }
  if (c.properties.token) {
    println("   token: " + c.token)
  }
  if (c.properties.subscriptionId) {
    println("   subscriptionId: " + c.subscriptionId)
  }
  if (c.properties.clientId) {
    println("   clientId: " + c.clientId)
  }
  if (c.properties.tenant) {
    println("   tenant: " + c.tenant)
  }
  if (c.properties.clientSecret) {
    println("   clientSecret: " + c.clientSecret)
  }
  if (c.properties.plainClientSecret) {
    println("   plainClientSecret: " + c.plainClientSecret)
  }
  println("")
}
```

Comment: Edited code to add secretBytes, apiToken, and token support.

Comment: Hi there!
If you want to see an AWS credentials:
`if (c.getAccessKey()) {
    println("   Access Key: " + c.getAccessKey())   
    println("   Secret Key: " + c.getSecretKey())   
  }
`

Comment: If you have actual binary data in secretBytes, you can base64-encode it so it displays cleanly in the console:
`if (c.properties.secretBytes) {
      println("    secretBytes: ")
      println("\n" + c.secretBytes.getPlainData().encodeBase64())
      println("")
    }
`

Answer (score 15):

This is a combined script that concatenates multiple findings on this topic together. It lists all credentials from all scopes of Jenkins, not just the root scope. Hopefully it helps.

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials


Set<Credentials> allCredentials = new HashSet<Credentials>();


def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
      com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class
);


allCredentials.addAll(creds)


Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder.class).each{ f ->
 creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
      com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class, f)
  allCredentials.addAll(creds)

}


for (c in allCredentials) {
  println(c.id)
  if (c.properties.username) {
    println("   description: " + c.description)
  }
  if (c.properties.username) {
    println("   username: " + c.username)
  }
  if (c.properties.password) {
    println("   password: " + c.password)
  }
  if (c.properties.passphrase) {
    println("   passphrase: " + c.passphrase)
  }
  if (c.properties.secret) {
    println("   secret: " + c.secret)
  }
  if (c.properties.privateKeySource) {
    println("   privateKey: " + c.getPrivateKey())
  }
  println("")
}
```

Comment: This is a useful answer and snippet which do the trick. Thx @vkozyrev

Comment: I didn't get it to work until I removed most the println:s. Kept getting 50x error. I left just the `println(c.id)` but that was OK as I was just looking for a particular ID anyway.

Comment: Thanks I used this, except I replaced everything inside the for loop with `c.properties.each { println "$it.key -> $it.value" }` to dump everything

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to have a list of available credentials and found this:

```
def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials( com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class, Jenkins.instance, null, null );

for (c in creds) {
   println(c.id + ": " + c.description)
}
```

Got it from here:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Printing+a+list+of+credentials+and+their+IDs

Comment: You should add the relevant information to your answer to prevent the loss if the link dies.

Comment: This doesn't get any credentials in folders.

Answer (score 2):

This is quick dirty code, it will print some of the credential types on jenkins, if you need more you can use the different classes defined here:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/common

```
def StandardUsernameCredentials = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
    com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class,
    Jenkins.instance,
    null,
    null ); for (c in StandardUsernameCredentials) {
     println(c.id + ": " + c.description) } def StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
    com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials.class,
    Jenkins.instance,
    null,
    null ); for (c in StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials) {
     println(c.id + ": " + c.description) }

def IdCredentials = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
    com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.IdCredentials.class,
    Jenkins.instance,
    null,
    null ); for (c in IdCredentials) {
     println(c.id + ": " + c.description) }

def StandardCertificateCredentialsCredentials = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
    com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardCertificateCredentials.class,
    Jenkins.instance,
    null,
    null ); for (c in StandardCertificateCredentialsCredentials) {
     println(c.id + ": " + c.description) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that I modified from the accepted answer.  We use azure credentials and this will print them.  It will also print the `c.properties` if the secret type is not found.

```
    com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class
)

for (c in creds) {
  println(c.id)
  if (c.properties.username) {
    println("   description: " + c.description)
  }
  if (c.properties.username) {
    println("   username: |" + c.username + "|")
  }
  else if (c.properties.password) {
    println("   password: |" + c.password + "|")
  }
  else if (c.properties.passphrase) {
    println("   passphrase: |" + c.passphrase + "|")
  }
  else if (c.properties.secret) {
    println("   secret: |" + c.secret + "|")
  }
  else if (c.properties.privateKeySource) {
    println("   privateKey: " + c.getPrivateKey())
  }
  else if (c.properties.clientId) {
    println("   clientId    : " + c.getClientId())
    println("   tenant      : " + c.getTenant())
    println("   subscription: " + c.getSubscriptionId())
    println("   secret      : " + hudson.util.Secret.fromString(c.getClientSecret()))
  }
  else {
    println("unknown secret type")
    println(c.properties)
  }
  println("")
}
```

Comment: The beginning of the snippet is missing

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all properties without silly if's:

```
def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials( com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class, Jenkins.instance, null, null );

for (c in creds) {
   println(c.id + ": " + c.description)
   c.properties.each { println it }
   println()
   println()
}
```

Your security team might not be happy you doing this :)